# Good python application for source code studying

Tags: python

I am currently learning Python and I would like to study the source code of a well written all Python application. Can you point me in the right direction?

I am particularly interested in database access and Web programming.

Comment: Could you please explain how your question relates to Ubuntu? Otherwise it’s off topic on Ask**Ubuntu**. General programming question would be better over on [SO].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to check out Django, a very popular content management system. Plenty of web application and database access code to study in that app, including good practices like database agnosticism and modularity.

Comment: Django - I should have thought of that! Thank you very much!

Comment: You can add great documentation and great test cases to the mix. I use django at work daily, and reading its source code to resolve some doubt is a joy: clear, commented, well structured...